# Codeigniter foreach doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code.compiler doesn't enter in foreach. I don't know why? although i write this foreach in other function and works,please any one help me.
in model

```
public function getting_profile_check($u)
{
    $this->db->where('login_name', $u);


    return $this->db->get('profile_check');

}
```

and in controller

```
public function get_profile_check($user)
{
    echo"i in get profile check";
    $d=$this->login_m->getting_profile_check($user);

    $data=array('check_res'=>$d,'first_time'=>"no");

    foreach($d->result() as $field)
        { 
        echo"i in for each in get";
          $image=$field->image_c;

          $view=$field->overview_c;
          $certi=$field->certi_c;
          $edu=$field->edu_c;
          $hopp=$field->hopp_c;
          $lang=$field->lang_c;
           echo"session".$image."   " .$edu;

        }


    }
```

Comment: I discovered the error .when i pass user from view  the user become 20%user this was error i dont know why. so i get the user from controller thanks for your effort with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function get_profile_check($user)
{
    echo"i in get profile check";
    $d = $this->login_m->getting_profile_check($user);

    $data=array('check_res'=>$d,'first_time'=>"no");

    foreach($d as $field)
    { 
        echo"i in for each in get";
        $image=$field->image_c;

        $view=$field->overview_c;
        $certi=$field->certi_c;
        $edu=$field->edu_c;
        $hopp=$field->hopp_c;
        $lang=$field->lang_c;
        echo"session".$image."   " .$edu;

    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function getting_profile_check($u)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where('login_name', $u);
    $query = $this->db->get('profile_check');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I try this code  but the  same result doesn't enter in for each and doesn't echo"i in foreach in get "

Comment: make sure all data are pasing with the array.

Comment: this function in controller pass data   public function intialize_profile_array($user)
{
 
 
 $data_array=array(
 'login_name'=>$user,
 'image_c'=>"no",
 'overview_c'=>"no",
 'certi_c'=>"no",
 'edu_c'=>"no",
 'hopp_c'=>"no",
 'lang_c'=>"no"   );
 
 
 $this->login_m->insert_profile_check($data_array,$user);


} and in model  public function insert_profile_check($data)
{
 
$this->db->insert('profile_check', $data); 
 
}  and already is inserted in database

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in model:

```
public function getting_profile_check($u)
{

   $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('profile_check')
            ->where('login_name', $u);


   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows > 0){
       return $query->result_array();
    }

}
```

in controller:

```
public function get_profile_check($user)
{
   echo"i in get profile check";

   $d=$this->login_m->getting_profile_check($user);


    foreach ($d as $row ) {

        echo $row['name_of_table_column'];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
public function getting_profile_check($u)
{
   $this->db->where('login_name', $u);
   return $this->db->get('profile_check')->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_profile_check($user)
{
   echo"i in get profile check";
   $d=$this->login_m->getting_profile_check($user);

   foreach ($d as $row ) 
   {
        echo $row->name_of_table_column;
   }
}
```